# Why does Date addition result in a string?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand this behaviour:

```
var d = new Date();

console.log(+d); // 1458049171381
console.log(1 + d); // '1Tue Mar 15 2016 09:39:31 GMT-0400 (EDT)'
```

In contrast to:

```
var obj = {
  valueOf: function () {
    return 123;
  }
};

console.log(+obj); // 123
console.log(1 + obj); // 124
```

Why does the `Date` addition result in a `string` when `Date.prototype.valueOf` returns a `number`?

Here is naive translation of the [Addition Operator's spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1) to JavaScript

```
function ToPrimitive(x) {
  return x.valueOf();
}

function IsString(x) {
  return typeof x === 'string';
}

function ToString(x) {
  return x.toString();
}

function ToNumber(x) {
  try {
    return parseFloat(x);
  } catch (e) {
    return NaN;
  }
}

function AdditionOperator(lval, rval) {

  let lprim = ToPrimitive(lval);
  let rprim = ToPrimitive(rval);

  if (IsString(lprim) || IsString(rprim)) {
    return ToString(lprim) + ToString(rprim);
  } else {
    return ToNumber(lprim) + ToNumber(rprim);
  }
}
```

However, if I invoke this with a `Date` object, it returns a numeric value:

```
AdditionOperator(new Date(), 1) // 1458049347088
```

Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: did you read the NOTE 1 ?

Comment: @iliacholy ya i was wrong.it was a misconception. Thanks for the example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Walk-through:

- Before the addition takes place, both the left and right values
  of the binary operation are converted to primitives (`string` or `number`).
- Depending on the context of the value, it might be provided a 'hint' which suggests which primitive type it should become.
- If no hint is provided, it will default to its preferred type. All `Object`s have a preferred type of `number` except for `Date`, which prefers `string` (and confuses everyone).

As per the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-addition-operator-plus-runtime-semantics-evaluation)

> All standard objects except Date objects handle the absence of a hint
>   as if the hint Number were given; Date objects handle the absence of a
>   hint as if the hint String were given. Exotic objects may handle the
>   absence of a hint in some other manner.

And in case of Date they make an [exception](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toprimitive)

> Of the objects defined in this specification only Date objects (see
>   20.3.4.45) and Symbol objects (see 19.4.3.4) over-ride the default ToPrimitive behaviour. Date objects treat no hint as if the hint were
>   String.

Also, check [this](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype-@@toprimitive)

> This function is called by ECMAScript language operators to convert a
>   Date object to a primitive value. The allowed values for hint are
>   "default", "number", and "string". Date objects, are unique among
>   built-in ECMAScript object in that they treat "default" as being
>   equivalent to "string", All other built-in ECMAScript objects treat
>   "default" as being equivalent to "number".

So, Date is used as String only.